# Is there are any tutorial of how to build software with TFS

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have just started using TFS2010 as a source control, moving away from VSS. So the next step will be build. Is there are any handy tutorial on how to do that? Currently we are using Visual Studio setup project to build installation package.

**Update**

TFS server is already set up

No build controllers

We have Sharepoint integration, but have not used it actively

All machines are under single domain

We have currently around 10 solutions in maintenance to build

As a installation package we are using msi, and will be excellent to have ability to build msi using Visual Studio setup project or any other alternative packager

Comment: Elaborate with how far along you are.  Is the TFS server already set up?  What about the build controllers?  Will you require Sharepoint integration?  Will all the machines be on the same domain?  What do you need to build, just a single project or solution?  Not sure what your reference to the installation package means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe that a Setup Project can be built by Team Build.

Aside from that, the reason you're not finding tutorials is that it's pretty trivial:

1. Get your build servers set up. See the setup documentation for that.
2. Open a solution you are currently building locally.
3. Go to Team Explorer, right-click the "Builds" node, and choose "New Build Definition"
4. Give it a name like "Manual build"
5. Click the "Build Defaults" tab and specify the path to a share to use as a drop folder for the build outputs
6. Save the build definition

You're done. That has created a build definition for the solutions in the current workspace, that you can trigger manually by right-clicking the definition in Team Explorer and choosing "Queue New Build".

Comment: It's not so much that Setup Projects can't be built by TFS Build. It's more accurate to say that they can't be built outside of Visual Studio. There is a hack you can use to invoke DevEnv.exe from your build process to build them, but I'd recommend migrating your setup to WiX (if you need an MSI package) or NSIS (if you just need an installable executable).

Comment: Thanks, Jim. Got some links for the OP?

Comment: WiX is at http://wix.sourceforge.net/ and NSIS is at http://nsis.sourceforge.net/. Just to clarify, WiX is a Microsoft open source project while NSIS is not from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

There are few blogs, little posts here and there. Unfortunately, you should not expect to find step-by-step tutorial for every problem you encounter or functionality you want to implement.

When I started implementing tools against TFS, I found most usefull following link:

1. [Top level TFS API page in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx)
2. [TFS Test API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465178.aspx)
3. [Dennis Stone blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/densto/) (Generally MSDN blog are best source for learning).
4. [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/categories)
5. Asking questions in MSDN forums or here in stackoverflow

Comment: -1 what does any of that have to do with using TFS for builds?

Comment: Yes: With the ORIGINALLY given information (1) Link 1 is top level and drills down to build or any RELATED areas(2) The fact that there is no much info applies to it (3) MSDN Blogs/Forurms are good place to search for problems/answers encountered (4) Dennis Stone's blog is good source for it.. Which part you were NOT able to digest?

Comment: Still don't see what any of that has to do with building code. Even the original didn't ask about APIs, for instance.

Comment: Have you ever heard of programmatic way of doing something?

Comment: Heard of it, and often use it, but it's not what the OP asked for.

Comment: From the original post, it's NOT clear whether he wants "manual" or "automated" way of doing it. Anyways, it's NOT a place to make nonsense discussions. At least 2 people found my answer helpful.

Comment: @JohnSaunders let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2143/discussion-between-azho-kg-and-john-saunders)